# i deleted a commit file from work repo and i want to get back it from local repo in GIT

Tags: git, github

i deleted a commit file from working repo but the file is available in local repo in GIT and file is not available in remote repo as well.

now my question is how we can get that deleted file that is available in local repo but not in work repo.

Repo =repository

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the file is stored in a previours commit in the history of the repo, restoring it to its value in that previous commit is a simple :

```
git checkout <commit sha1> -- path/to/file
```

The "zone" where files are added before being committed is called : the index.

If you want to get a file back from the index :

```
git checkout -- path/to/file
```

Comment: file is already in local repo.... i just want to copy my file from local to work repo.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and describe more precisely what you want to do, and the actions you have taken ? There seems to be a confusion between "commit" and "file" in the wording.

Comment: I had a file in my work directory, i added that file to local repo by "git add filename".
then i deleted that file from my work directory using "rm -f filename".
Now i want the file from local repo to work repo. How to get this.

Comment: That's a much more accurate description of your problem. What you call "work repo" is called "worktree" in git, or simply "working directory".

Answer (score -1):

Simple steps:

1. Take backup of that file in local.
2. Make up to date your local repository.
3. Add that file in you directory.
4. Commit your new file and push the code.

Comment: thanks but i am bit new and not sure how to take backup from local to work repo.